# Issue a request for a user to join a group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-app-requests, facebook-group, facebook-game-groups

I'm using the app and game groups API atm and am trying to let users Join app groups that they see while browsing. I've researched how to do this and am not sure how to do this.

It seems that I would have to issue a user to user request from the user wishing to join the group to the admin of the group however, after looking at the Facebook requests documentation it is seems that user-user requests are only possible through canvas apps. WTF.

Is this true and how would I issue a user to user request for someone to join a group?

Please Stackoverflow help me.. You are overflowing with solutions!

Comment: Have temporary fix but essentially adds another step. Is there an actual way through the Facebook API to request to join a group?

Comment: Essentially the Join Clan button in the picture from the following link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/app-game-groups/#view

Comment: I think your app just needs to post to /GROUP_ID/members/USER_ID where USER_ID is the current user's FB id. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/app-game-groups/#add_user
If the group is closed then the admin should automatically receive a request to join (sent by Facebook itself) and be able to approve it?

Comment: madebydavid you have gone IN! Should have seen this was approaching from the wrong mindframe. Thanks! Answer so I can up your score and things!

Comment: Wow, cool - ok will post an answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app just needs to post to /GROUP_ID/members/USER_ID where USER_ID is the current user's FB id. See the Add User to Group documentation [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/app-game-groups/#add_user).

If the group is closed then the admin should automatically receive a request to join (sent by Facebook itself) and then be able to approve it.